# Puppet : Install a .deb

Tags: ubuntu, puppet

How can I install a .deb file in a puppet custom module?

I want to run this command in a puppet

```
wget https://repo.percona.com/apt/percona-release_0.1-6.$(lsb_release -sc)_all.deb 
sudo dpkg -i percona-release_0.1-6.$(lsb_release -sc)_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install percona-xtradb-cluster-full-57
```

and this is my current percona.pp

```
class percona {

    exec{'percona_deb':
      command => "/usr/bin/wget -q https://repo.percona.com/apt/percona-release_0.1-6.$(lsb_release -sc)_all.deb -O /tmp/percona-re$
      creates => "/tmp/percona-release_0.1-6.$(lsb_release -sc)_all.deb",
    }
}
```

running the script in agent `/opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet agent --test` will download the .deb file

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you using the native resource type [package](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/type.html#package). Then, you can use the provider [dpkg](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/type.html#package-provider-dpkg) and the [source](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/type.html#package-attribute-source) you mentioned above to create the solution you are looking for.

For example:

```
package {'percona':
  provider => dpkg,
  source   => <source_url>,
}
```

For more resource attributes, you can consult the documentation [here](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/type.html#package-attributes).

Comment: In my testing, the `dpkg` provider does not support URLs (it only supports local files).  [Puppet will not download files for you](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/types/package.html#package-attribute-source).  You will need to use another resource to download the file first (eg exec, etc).